# Graylog failing to send emails (SMTP)

Tags: smtp, graylog

i am trying to let greylog2 send me email alters but i am getting this error no matter what i try? i am trying to use smtp.gmail.com as email server.

This is the error message i am getting

> The Graylog server encountered an error while trying to send an email. This is the detailed error message: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Missing final '@domain' in string `"guldberg72@gmail.com"'' (javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Missing final '@domain' in string`"guldberg72@gmail.com"'')

```
# If you are running more than one instances of graylog2-server you have to select one of these
# instances as master. The master will perform some periodical tasks that non-masters won't perform.
is_master = true

# The auto-generated node ID will be stored in this file and read after restarts. It is a good idea
# to use an absolute file path here if you are starting graylog2-server from init scripts or similar.
node_id_file = /etc/graylog/server/node-id

# You MUST set a secret to secure/pepper the stored user passwords here. Use at least 64 characters.
# Generate one by using for example: pwgen -N 1 -s 96
password_secret = IqqqPjvWdo24LlqhDJktOi0wjEtvvGOSBoIZSFwgdWyqyMR4SqPbOPPv97AoblUv3jPQkKr1Wo0INYgxmX9nTEwxYkcyKaau

# The default root user is named 'admin'
#root_username = admin

# You MUST specify a hash password for the root user (which you only need to initially set up the
# system and in case you lose connectivity to your authentication backend)
# This password cannot be changed using the API or via the web interface. If you need to change it,
# modify it in this file.
# Create one by using for example: echo -n yourpassword | shasum -a 256
# and put the resulting hash value into the following line
root_password_sha2 = 79e192043f526a4bc2f0431ab7b76b90a1dcfbe65ff33f346a03118226eab1e4

# The email address of the root user.
# Default is empty
root_email = "guldberg72@gmail.com" 

# The time zone setting of the root user.
# The configured time zone must be parseable by http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forID-java.lang.String-
# Default is UTC
#root_timezone = UTC

# Set plugin directory here (relative or absolute)
plugin_dir = /usr/share/graylog-server/plugin

# REST API listen URI. Must be reachable by other graylog2-server nodes if you run a cluster.
rest_listen_uri = http://127.0.0.1:12900/


# REST API transport address. Defaults to the value of rest_listen_uri. Exception: If rest_listen_uri
# is set to a wildcard IP address (0.0.0.0) the first non-loopback IPv4 system address is used.
# If set, his will be promoted in the cluster discovery APIs, so other nodes may try to connect on
# this address and it is used to generate URLs addressing entities in the REST API. (see rest_listen_uri)
# You will need to define this, if your Graylog server is running behind a HTTP proxy that is rewriting
# the scheme, host name or URI.
#rest_transport_uri = http://192.168.1.1:12900/

# Enable CORS headers for REST API. This is necessary for JS-clients accessing the server directly.
# If these are disabled, modern browsers will not be able to retrieve resources from the server.
# This is disabled by default. Uncomment the next line to enable it.
#rest_enable_cors = true

# Enable GZIP support for REST API. This compresses API responses and therefore helps to reduce
# overall round trip times. This is disabled by default. Uncomment the next line to enable it.
#rest_enable_gzip = true

# Enable HTTPS support for the REST API. This secures the communication with the REST API with
# TLS to prevent request forgery and eavesdropping. This is disabled by default. Uncomment the
# next line to enable it.
#rest_enable_tls = true

# The X.509 certificate file to use for securing the REST API.
#rest_tls_cert_file = /path/to/graylog2.crt

# The private key to use for securing the REST API.
#rest_tls_key_file = /path/to/graylog2.key

# The password to unlock the private key used for securing the REST API.
#rest_tls_key_password = secret

# The maximum size of a single HTTP chunk in bytes.
#rest_max_chunk_size = 8192
# The maximum size of the HTTP request headers in bytes.
#rest_max_header_size = 8192

# The maximal length of the initial HTTP/1.1 line in bytes.
#rest_max_initial_line_length = 4096

# The size of the execution handler thread pool used exclusively for serving the REST API.
#rest_thread_pool_size = 16

# The size of the worker thread pool used exclusively for serving the REST API.
#rest_worker_threads_max_pool_size = 16

# Embedded Elasticsearch configuration file
# pay attention to the working directory of the server, maybe use an absolute path here
#elasticsearch_config_file = /etc/graylog/server/elasticsearch.yml

# Graylog will use multiple indices to store documents in. You can configured the strategy it uses to determine
# when to rotate the currently active write index.
# It supports multiple rotation strategies:
#   - "count" of messages per index, use elasticsearch_max_docs_per_index below to configure
#   - "size" per index, use elasticsearch_max_size_per_index below to configure
# valid values are "count", "size" and "time", default is "count"
rotation_strategy = count

# (Approximate) maximum number of documents in an Elasticsearch index before a new index
# is being created, also see no_retention and elasticsearch_max_number_of_indices.
# Configure this if you used 'rotation_strategy = count' above.
elasticsearch_max_docs_per_index = 20000000

# (Approximate) maximum size in bytes per Elasticsearch index on disk before a new index is being created, also see
# no_retention and elasticsearch_max_number_of_indices. Default is 1GB.
# Configure this if you used 'rotation_strategy = size' above.
#elasticsearch_max_size_per_index = 1073741824

# (Approximate) maximum time before a new Elasticsearch index is being created, also see
# no_retention and elasticsearch_max_number_of_indices. Default is 1 day.
# Configure this if you used 'rotation_strategy = time' above.
# Please note that this rotation period does not look at the time specified in the received messages, but is
# using the real clock value to decide when to rotate the index!
# Specify the time using a duration and a suffix indicating which unit you want:
#  1w  = 1 week
#  1d  = 1 day
#  12h = 12 hours
# Permitted suffixes are: d for day, h for hour, m for minute, s for second.
#elasticsearch_max_time_per_index = 1d

# Disable checking the version of Elasticsearch for being compatible with this Graylog release.
# WARNING: Using Graylog with unsupported and untested versions of Elasticsearch may lead to data loss!
#elasticsearch_disable_version_check = true

# Disable message retention on this node, i. e. disable Elasticsearch index rotation.
#no_retention = false

# How many indices do you want to keep?
elasticsearch_max_number_of_indices = 20

# Decide what happens with the oldest indices when the maximum number of indices is reached.
# The following strategies are availble:
#   - delete # Deletes the index completely (Default)
#   - close # Closes the index and hides it from the system. Can be re-opened later.
retention_strategy = delete

# How many Elasticsearch shards and replicas should be used per index? Note that this only applies to newly created indices.
elasticsearch_shards = 1 
elasticsearch_replicas = 0

# Prefix for all Elasticsearch indices and index aliases managed by Graylog.
elasticsearch_index_prefix = graylog2

# Do you want to allow searches with leading wildcards? This can be extremely resource hungry and should only
# be enabled with care. See also: https://www.graylog.org/documentation/general/queries/
allow_leading_wildcard_searches = false

# Do you want to allow searches to be highlighted? Depending on the size of your messages this can be memory hungry and
# should only be enabled after making sure your Elasticsearch cluster has enough memory.
allow_highlighting = false

# settings to be passed to elasticsearch's client (overriding those in the provided elasticsearch_config_file)
# all these
# this must be the same as for your Elasticsearch cluster
#elasticsearch_cluster_name = graylog2

# you could also leave this out, but makes it easier to identify the graylog2 client instance
#elasticsearch_node_name = graylog2-server

# we don't want the graylog2 server to store any data, or be master node
#elasticsearch_node_master = false
#elasticsearch_node_data = false

# use a different port if you run multiple Elasticsearch nodes on one machine
#elasticsearch_transport_tcp_port = 9350

# we don't need to run the embedded HTTP server here
elasticsearch_http_enabled = false

#elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_multicast_enabled = false
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 10.0.2.13:9300 

# Change the following setting if you are running into problems with timeouts during Elasticsearch cluster discovery.
# The setting is specified in milliseconds, the default is 5000ms (5 seconds).
#elasticsearch_cluster_discovery_timeout = 5000

# the following settings allow to change the bind addresses for the Elasticsearch client in graylog2
# these settings are empty by default, letting Elasticsearch choose automatically,
# override them here or in the 'elasticsearch_config_file' if you need to bind to a special address
# refer to http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/modules-network.html
# for special values here
#elasticsearch_network_host =
#elasticsearch_network_bind_host =
#elasticsearch_network_publish_host =

# The total amount of time discovery will look for other Elasticsearch nodes in the cluster
# before giving up and declaring the current node master.
#elasticsearch_discovery_initial_state_timeout = 3s

# Analyzer (tokenizer) to use for message and full_message field. The "standard" filter usually is a good idea.
# All supported analyzers are: standard, simple, whitespace, stop, keyword, pattern, language, snowball, custom
# Elasticsearch documentation: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/
# Note that this setting only takes effect on newly created indices.
elasticsearch_analyzer = standard

# Global request timeout for Elasticsearch requests (e. g. during search, index creation, or index time-range
# calculations) based on a best-effort to restrict the runtime of Elasticsearch operations.
# Default: 1m
#elasticsearch_request_timeout = 1m

# Batch size for the Elasticsearch output. This is the maximum (!) number of messages the Elasticsearch output
# module will get at once and write to Elasticsearch in a batch call. If the configured batch size has not been
# reached within output_flush_interval seconds, everything that is available will be flushed at once. Remember
# that every outputbuffer processor manages its own batch and performs its own batch write calls.
# ("outputbuffer_processors" variable)
output_batch_size = 500

# Flush interval (in seconds) for the Elasticsearch output. This is the maximum amount of time between two
# batches of messages written to Elasticsearch. It is only effective at all if your minimum number of messages
# for this time period is less than output_batch_size * outputbuffer_processors.
output_flush_interval = 1

# As stream outputs are loaded only on demand, an output which is failing to initialize will be tried over and
# over again. To prevent this, the following configuration options define after how many faults an output will
# not be tried again for an also configurable amount of seconds.
output_fault_count_threshold = 5
output_fault_penalty_seconds = 30

# The number of parallel running processors.
# Raise this number if your buffers are filling up.
processbuffer_processors = 5
outputbuffer_processors = 3

#outputbuffer_processor_keep_alive_time = 5000
#outputbuffer_processor_threads_core_pool_size = 3
#outputbuffer_processor_threads_max_pool_size = 30

# UDP receive buffer size for all message inputs (e. g. SyslogUDPInput).
#udp_recvbuffer_sizes = 1048576

# Wait strategy describing how buffer processors wait on a cursor sequence. (default: sleeping)
# Possible types:
#  - yielding
#     Compromise between performance and CPU usage.
#  - sleeping
#     Compromise between performance and CPU usage. Latency spikes can occur after quiet periods.
#  - blocking
#     High throughput, low latency, higher CPU usage.
#  - busy_spinning
#     Avoids syscalls which could introduce latency jitter. Best when threads can be bound to specific CPU cores.
processor_wait_strategy = blocking

# Size of internal ring buffers. Raise this if raising outputbuffer_processors does not help anymore.
# For optimum performance your LogMessage objects in the ring buffer should fit in your CPU L3 cache.
# Start server with --statistics flag to see buffer utilization.
# Must be a power of 2. (512, 1024, 2048, ...)
ring_size = 65536

inputbuffer_ring_size = 65536
inputbuffer_processors = 2
inputbuffer_wait_strategy = blocking

# Enable the disk based message journal.
message_journal_enabled = true

# The directory which will be used to store the message journal. The directory must me exclusively used by Graylog and
# must not contain any other files than the ones created by Graylog itself.
message_journal_dir = /var/lib/graylog-server/journal

# Journal hold messages before they could be written to Elasticsearch.
# For a maximum of 12 hours or 5 GB whichever happens first.
# During normal operation the journal will be smaller.
#message_journal_max_age = 12h
#message_journal_max_size = 5gb

#message_journal_flush_age = 1m
#message_journal_flush_interval = 1000000
#message_journal_segment_age = 1h
#message_journal_segment_size = 100mb

# Number of threads used exclusively for dispatching internal events. Default is 2.
#async_eventbus_processors = 2

# EXPERIMENTAL: Dead Letters
# Every failed indexing attempt is logged by default and made visible in the web-interface. You can enable
# the experimental dead letters feature to write every message that was not successfully indexed into the
# MongoDB "dead_letters" collection to make sure that you never lose a message. The actual writing of dead
# letter should work fine already but it is not heavily tested yet and will get more features in future
# releases.
dead_letters_enabled = false

# How many seconds to wait between marking node as DEAD for possible load balancers and starting the actual
# shutdown process. Set to 0 if you have no status checking load balancers in front.
lb_recognition_period_seconds = 3

# Every message is matched against the configured streams and it can happen that a stream contains rules which
# take an unusual amount of time to run, for example if its using regular expressions that perform excessive backtracking.
# This will impact the processing of the entire server. To keep such misbehaving stream rules from impacting other
# streams, Graylog limits the execution time for each stream.
# The default values are noted below, the timeout is in milliseconds.
# If the stream matching for one stream took longer than the timeout value, and this happened more than "max_faults" times
# that stream is disabled and a notification is shown in the web interface.
#stream_processing_timeout = 2000
#stream_processing_max_faults = 3

# Length of the interval in seconds in which the alert conditions for all streams should be checked
# and alarms are being sent.
#alert_check_interval = 60

# Since 0.21 the graylog2 server supports pluggable output modules. This means a single message can be written to multiple
# outputs. The next setting defines the timeout for a single output module, including the default output module where all
# messages end up.
#
# Time in milliseconds to wait for all message outputs to finish writing a single message.
#output_module_timeout = 10000

# Time in milliseconds after which a detected stale master node is being rechecked on startup.
#stale_master_timeout = 2000

# Time in milliseconds which Graylog is waiting for all threads to stop on shutdown.
#shutdown_timeout = 30000

# MongoDB connection string
# See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/ for details
mongodb_uri = mongodb://localhost/graylog2

# Authenticate against the MongoDB server
#mongodb_uri = mongodb://grayloguser:secret@localhost:27017/graylog2

# Use a replica set instead of a single host
#mongodb_uri = mongodb://grayloguser:secret@localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/graylog2

# Increase this value according to the maximum connections your MongoDB server can handle from a single client
# if you encounter MongoDB connection problems.
mongodb_max_connections = 100

# Number of threads allowed to be blocked by MongoDB connections multiplier. Default: 5
# If mongodb_max_connections is 100, and mongodb_threads_allowed_to_block_multiplier is 5,
# then 500 threads can block. More than that and an exception will be thrown.
# http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html#threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier
mongodb_threads_allowed_to_block_multiplier = 5

# Drools Rule File (Use to rewrite incoming log messages)
# See: https://www.graylog.org/documentation/general/rewriting/
#rules_file = /etc/graylog/server/rules.drl

 Email transport
transport_email_enabled = true
transport_email_hostname = smtp.gmail.com 
transport_email_port = 465 
transport_email_use_auth = true
transport_email_use_tls = true
#transport_email_use_ssl = true
transport_email_auth_username = techknighteu
transport_email_auth_password = mysecretpassword
transport_email_subject_prefix = [graylog2]
transport_email_from_email = techknighteu@gmail.com

# Specify and uncomment this if you want to include links to the stream in your stream alert mails.
# This should define the fully qualified base url to your web interface exactly the same way as it is accessed by your users.
#transport_email_web_interface_url = https://graylog2.example.com

# The default connect timeout for outgoing HTTP connections.
# Values must be a positive duration (and between 1 and 2147483647 when converted to milliseconds).
# Default: 5s
#http_connect_timeout = 5s

# The default read timeout for outgoing HTTP connections.
# Values must be a positive duration (and between 1 and 2147483647 when converted to milliseconds).
# Default: 10s
#http_read_timeout = 10s

# The default write timeout for outgoing HTTP connections.
# Values must be a positive duration (and between 1 and 2147483647 when converted to milliseconds).
# Default: 10s
#http_write_timeout = 10s

# HTTP proxy for outgoing HTTP connections
#http_proxy_uri =

# Disable the optimization of Elasticsearch indices after index cycling. This may take some load from Elasticsearch
# on heavily used systems with large indices, but it will decrease search performance. The default is to optimize
# cycled indices.
#disable_index_optimization = true

# Optimize the index down to <= index_optimization_max_num_segments. A higher number may take some load from Elasticsearch
# on heavily used systems with large indices, but it will decrease search performance. The default is 1.
#index_optimization_max_num_segments = 1

# The threshold of the garbage collection runs. If GC runs take longer than this threshold, a system notification
# will be generated to warn the administrator about possible problems with the system. Default is 1 second.
#gc_warning_threshold = 1s

# Connection timeout for a configured LDAP server (e. g. ActiveDirectory) in milliseconds.
#ldap_connection_timeout = 2000

# Enable collection of Graylog-related metrics into MongoDB
# WARNING: This will add *a lot* of data into your MongoDB database on a regular interval (1 second)!
# DEPRECATED: This setting and the respective feature will be removed in a future version of Graylog.
#enable_metrics_collection = false

# Disable the use of SIGAR for collecting system stats
#disable_sigar = false

# Amount of time of inactivity after which collectors are flagged as inactive (Default: 1 minute)
#collector_inactive_threshold = 1m

# Amount of time after which inactive collectors are purged (Default: 14 days)
#collector_expiration_threshold = 14d

# The default cache time for dashboard widgets. (Default: 10 seconds, minimum: 1 second)
#dashboard_widget_default_cache_time = 10s

mongodb_useauth = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I diffed your config with mine:

```
$ diff -Nau /tmp/me /tmp/dan
--- /tmp/me 2015-10-31 12:31:31.359941839 +0000
+++ /tmp/dan    2015-10-31 12:30:57.833941853 +0000
@@ -1,13 +1,13 @@
 # The email address of the root user.
-#root_email = ""
+root_email = "guldberg72@gmail.com"
 transport_email_enabled = true
 transport_email_hostname = smtp.gmail.com
-transport_email_port = 587
+transport_email_port = 465
 transport_email_use_auth = true
 transport_email_use_tls = true
-transport_email_use_ssl = false
-transport_email_auth_username = me@gmail.com
+#transport_email_use_ssl = true
+transport_email_auth_username = techknighteu
 transport_email_auth_password = mysecretpassword
 transport_email_subject_prefix = [graylog2]
-transport_email_from_email = graylog2@mydomain.com
+transport_email_from_email = techknighteu@gmail.com
 #transport_email_web_interface_url = https://graylog2.example.com
```

Don't know if that's any help.

What version of graylog are you running?

Comment: Going to look at it later ;) i am not 100% but i mean it is v. 1.2

Comment: Davey are you from denmark? Same time zone :p

Comment: thanks that did it! i had to outcomment the root email section